# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/R$string;

Tags: java, android, noclassdeffounderror

I tried out many things, but it does not solve my problem.

Full Error Code (kompletter Error Code):

```
05-16 09:59:53.428 25010-25010/main.faseflex.de.fgnapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: main.faseflex.de.fgnapp, PID: 25010
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/R$string;
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.StringResourceValueReader.<init>(Unknown Source:14)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions.fromResource(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source:19)
    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source:4)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1925)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1900)
    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source:23)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6578)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6133)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6043)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1764)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.R$string" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/main.faseflex.de.fgnapp-C4iBOV7sIO2cNc4pfCATmA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/main.faseflex.de.fgnapp-C4iBOV7sIO2cNc4pfCATmA==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.StringResourceValueReader.<init>(Unknown Source:14) 
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions.fromResource(Unknown Source:2) 
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source:19) 
    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source:4) 
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1925) 
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1900) 
    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source:23) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6578) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6133) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6043) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1764) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

build.gradle app:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    //buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "main.faseflex.de.fgnapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
        dexOptions {
            preDexLibraries true
        }
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.98.41"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            multiDexKeepFile file('multidex-config.txt')
        }

    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.4.0'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v7:25.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.SHashank02051997:FancyToast-Android:0.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '25.3.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

build.gradle project:

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="main.faseflex.de.fgnapp"
    tools:node="replace">

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="50"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="false"
        android:smallScreens="false"
        android:xlargeScreens="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/fgn_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:resizeableActivity="false"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/fgn_icon"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        ------------------------------------------------
        MAIN ACTIVITY
        ------------------------------------------------
        <activity
            android:name=".FGNmainActivity"
            android:label="FGN-App"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        ------------------------------------------------
        STUNDENPLAN
        ------------------------------------------------
        <activity
            android:name=".activity_timetable"
            android:label="FGN-App | Stundenplan"
            android:parentActivityName=".FGNmainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_BROWSER" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        ------------------------------------------------
        ESSENSBESTELLUNG
        ------------------------------------------------
        <activity
            android:name=".activity_food"
            android:label="FGN-App | Essenplan"
            android:parentActivityName=".FGNmainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_BROWSER" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        ------------------------------------------------
        MDV
        ------------------------------------------------
        <activity
            android:name=".activity_mdv"
            android:label="FGN-App | Verkehrsverbund"
            android:parentActivityName=".FGNmainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_BROWSER" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        ------------------------------------------------
        DOKUMENTE
        ------------------------------------------------
        <activity
            android:name=".activity_documents"
            android:label="FGN-App | Dokumente"
            android:parentActivityName=".FGNmainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_BROWSER" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        ------------------------------------------------
        NEWS
        ------------------------------------------------
        <activity
            android:name=".activity_news"
            android:label="FGN-App | News"
            android:parentActivityName=".FGNmainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_BROWSER" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        ------------------------------------------------
        LEHRER
        ------------------------------------------------
        <activity
            android:name=".activity_teachers"
            android:label="FGN-App | Lehrer"
            android:parentActivityName=".FGNmainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_BROWSER" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        ------------------------------------------------
        MOODLE
        ------------------------------------------------
        <activity
            android:name=".activity_moodle"
            android:label="FGN-App | Moodle"
            android:parentActivityName=".FGNmainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_BROWSER" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        ------------------------------------------------
        OFFICE 365
        ------------------------------------------------
        <activity
            android:name=".activity_office"
            android:label="FGN-App | Office 365"
            android:parentActivityName=".FGNmainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_BROWSER" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        ------------------------------------------------
        KONTAKT
        ------------------------------------------------
        <activity
            android:name=".activity_contact"
            android:label="FGN-App | Kontakt"
            android:parentActivityName=".FGNmainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_BROWSER" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        ------------------------------------------------
        TERMINE
        ------------------------------------------------
        <activity
            android:name=".activity_termine"
            android:label="FGN-App | Termine"
            android:parentActivityName=".FGNmainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_BROWSER" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        ------------------------------------------------
        MITTAGSBAND
        ------------------------------------------------
        <activity
            android:name=".activity_mittagsband"
            android:label="FGN-App | Mittagsband"
            android:parentActivityName=".FGNmainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_BROWSER" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        ------------------------------------------------
        FEEDBACK
        ------------------------------------------------
        <activity
            android:name=".activity_menu_feedback"
            android:label="FGN-App | Feedback"
            android:parentActivityName=".SettingsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        ------------------------------------------------
        IMPRESSUM
        ------------------------------------------------
        <activity
            android:name=".activity_menu_impressum"
            android:label="FGN-App | Impressum"
            android:parentActivityName=".FGNmainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        ------------------------------------------------
        FIREBASE
        ------------------------------------------------
        <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".FirebaseIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".MyInstanceIDListenerService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        ------------------------------------------------
        EINSTELLUNGEN
        ------------------------------------------------
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="FGN-App | Einstellungen"
            android:parentActivityName=".FGNmainActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="main.faseflex.de.fgnapp.FGNmainActivity" />
        </activity>
        ------------------------------------------------
        SPLASH SCREEN
        ------------------------------------------------
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        ------------------------------------------------
        CHANGELOG
        ------------------------------------------------
        <activity
            android:name=".ChangelogActivity"
            android:label="FGN-App | Changelog"
            android:parentActivityName=".SettingsActivity"></activity>
    </application>



</manifest>
```

I know what the NoClassDefFoundError does, but I did not find the problem. Ask if you need more files for solving the problem.

Comment: this may be multidex problem. Can you try 2ed solution from https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.

Comment: I didn't read all of your post, what happens if you remove proguard? Does exception still occur? Do other classes from that lib (within the same package) present at runtime?)

Comment: @Vishu I added multidex but it doesnt work :/

Comment: @deathangel908 I removed the line `proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'` but it doesn't work

Comment: You have some conflicting libs in the projects, check `./gradlew app:dependencies`

Comment: @deathangel908 I did it and the build was successful with 1 actionable task which was executed

Answer (score 44):

> If you are using **Realm plugin** in your app, then you could try
>   **upgrading your plugin** as it was one of the reason why app crashed while
>   running.

**Steps to update realm plugin:**

- Open `build.gradle(Project: Project_name_here)` file.
- Replace classpath of realm gradle plugin with the [latest stable version](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest) as follows:
- `classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:7.0.0"`

Also, please check for any **outdated plugins** within `build.gradle` file as it may be one of the reason why the app crashes.

**OR**

I faced similar issue **after updating Android Studio to 3.6** with **Gradle 3.6.0**.

> I **downgraded** my **Gradle to 3.5.3** in-order to resolve this issue until it gets fixed in future.

**Steps:**

- Open `build.gradle(Project: Project_name_here)` file.
- Replace classpath of android tools build gradle under dependencies with the following:
- `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'`

**Please Note:** This is a temporary fix. It may get fixed in future, so until then downgrade and continue with app development.

Answer (score 19):

If you have just updated your project to Gradle `3.6.0` and are using **Realm** there is a very high chance that this issue was caused by the **Realm plugin**.
Accordingly to [this](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/665#issuecomment-574431015) comment, this issue happens for older Realm plugin versions, less than `5.13.1`.
So just updating to the latest Realm version will most likely solve the problem.

As of the time of writing it was:
`classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:6.1.0"`

Comment: This works. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/665#issuecomment-574431015

Answer (score 9):

You have to update your ***REALM-PLUGIN*** and you need to write this in ***Top-Level Gradle (Project:Gradle)***, copy paste below "***classpath***" line:

```
buildscript {
  ... 
  dependencies {
    classpath 'io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:7.0.0' //<--Your answer.
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Hi I know its late in the question but for the current android version, I solved this problem.

## on build.grade project-level dependencies update your:

- com.android.tools.build:gradle to the latest stable (android updates don't do this)

  - **link here** -> [developer android gradle releases](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin)
- if using realm:

  - **link here** ->[realm lastest versions](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/)
- if using gms services

  - update it aswell

## on build.grade app-level update your dependencies

Some answers to this problem involved multidex and other fix's but none solved for me.

That's why this answer was made.

my current settings:

**project-level**

```
dependencies {
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
   classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:6.0.2"
   classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
}
```

app-level

```
dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.3.0'
  implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
  implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
  implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
  implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
  implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
  implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
  implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
  androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
  androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
  implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:5.15.3'
  implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0"
  implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
  implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
  implementation 'commons-validator:commons-validator:1.6'
  implementation 'com.appeaser.sublimepickerlibrary:sublimepickerlibrary:2.1.2'
  implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
  implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
  implementation 'com.evrencoskun.library:tableview:0.8.8'
  implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
  implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.9.1, 3.99.99]'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.4.3'
  implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-share:5.15.3'
  implementation('com.smartlook.recording:app:1.1.0-native')
}
```

Hope I could help a few!

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this due to `realm-db`

It was on an alpha build of gradle and a few other project-specific circumstances (AndroidX, Kotlin) so this isn't a general issue, but another thing to check

Comment: To expand on this answer, you may need to update classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.11.0" to classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.13.1" in project's build.gradle.

Answer (score 1):

Recently, after the update to `Gradle 3.6.4`(and newer versions) faced the same problem `ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.R$string"`.

In my case it was old deprecated `io.mironov.smuggler` plugin.

It seems that in most cases problem is with old plugins (especially ones thar use transform api), so to find which one you first should try to update them all. And if that doesn't help, just disable them one by one until app starts running with out the error.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see, this issue comes from version conflicts of dependencies in **'project level' build.gradle** file.
And especially caught when the gradle version is updated.

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'
        classpath "io.objectbox:objectbox-gradle-plugin:2.8.1"
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.4.1'
    }
}
```

When you update your gradle version (`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'`), ensure that your other classpath dependencies are also up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

i remove all of the firebase and gms dependencies from my project and error happens with leakcanary and so remove this. and again error happens with calligraphy3 and so on ...
i think its multidex bug.

Answer (score 0):

I recently also face same issue.

using `classpath('com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.2.1')`. and works after disabling it.

Answer (score -2):

I had same problem, so be sure for class which is extending application to have below :

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

Otherwise you need to make clean - rebuild.